# Externalize the absolute path names in log-stash configuration and using relative path in patterns_dir

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Hi logstash experts please help me
While doing logstash configuration in the input section

```
input 
{
    file 
    {
         path => "/TISUATWEB53/home/tisuat54/solstis/solstair-uat/solstis-persist-1/logs/solstispersist.log" #file to parse
         sincedb_path =>"/TISUATWEB53/home/tisuat54/solstis/solstair-uat/solstis-persist-1/logs/solstispersist.db" #file to save position (used after restart)
         start_position => "beginning" #start on the beginning of the file when no sincedb path created
    }
}  

filter {
    grok {
#    patterns_dir => ["../.././patterns/"]
     patterns_dir => ["/TISUATWEB53/home/tisuat54/Tmon_LogStash/tmon-agent-3.2.3/patterns/"]
     match => { "message" => "%{BEFORE_THREAD_NAME}(%{THREAD_NAME:thread_name})%{BEFORE_ANALYSISPROCESS_ID}(%{ONLY_DIGITS:analysisprocessId})%{BEFORE_INSERTIONMONITORING_ID}%{ONLY_DIGITS:insertionmonitorId}%{BEFORE_BIN_FILE}%{BINFILE:binfileName}"}
    }
}
```

Can we define file path in properties file and refer properties in path=> and sincedb_path=>  .
And also in filter section how to define relative path in patterns_dir .I have tried  patterns_dir => ["../../patterns/"] but not working

Comment: What do you mean by defining path in properties file?

Comment: I mean  path => "/TISUATWEB53/home/tisuat54/solstis/solstair-uat/solstis-persist-1/logs/solstispersist.log" here value of path that is "/TISUATWEB53/home/tisuat54/solstis/solstair-uat/solstis-persist-1/logs/solstispersist.log" wants to put in some property file and wnats use like  path =>%{propertyname}.Is there any way externalize the value of path ?

Comment: I think you can do that, as long it's an absolute path which you're giving. Did you try putting it in a prop file?

Comment: patterns_dir supports with filter not input.

Comment: The above comment was for the path related question which you asked above mine.

Comment: yes correct.In input section how to define full file using a property

Answer (score 2):

You can use environment variables in logstash, so you could do `${VAR_FROM_ENVIRONMENT}` in you file and then set that variable before starting logstash.  For example:

```
export VAR_FROM_ENVIRONMENT="/TISUATWEB53/home/tisuat54"
bin/logstash -f logstash.conf
```

If you are running a version of logstash before logstash-5, you'll need to add a `--allow-env` flag to your logstash command line.

Comment: Could you suggest how to use environment variables in case of input 
{
    file 
    {
         path

Comment: Hi please let me know i am waiting for the response.

Comment: Anywhere you put ${var} it gets substituted when the config file is read

Comment: export SOLSTAIRJVM1="/TISUATWEB53/home/tisuat54/solstis/solstair-uat/solstis-persist-1/logs/solstispersist.log"
and path => ${SOLSTAIRJVM1} in th logstash.config.And ran using ./tmon-agent.sh start config/linux/logstash.config --allow-env     Did not worked

Comment: fetched an invalid config {:config=>"input \n{\n    file \n\t{\n         path => ${SOLSTAIRJVM1}
\n", :reason=>"Expected one of #, \", ', -, [, { at line 5, column 18 (byte 40) after input \n{\n    file \n\t{\n         path => ", :level=>:error}

Comment: What version of logstash are you using?  It looks like the environment feature was first added in 2.3.0, so you'd need to use at least that version to get the ${var} syntax.

Comment: Logstash version i am using is 2.3.1.For you is it picking environment values in logstash config file ?